# Добавление на страницу функции и последующее ее выполнение при клике

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Имеется расширение, выводящее на определенной странице "123"

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "name",
    "version": "1.0.0.0",
    "description": "description",

    "content_scripts":[{
        "matches": [
            "http://ru.stackoverflow.com/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "content_scripts.js"
        ]
    }]
}
```

**content_scripts.js**

```
alert(123);
```

Необходимо добавить кнопку, при нажатии на которую будет выполняться функция. Допустим так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`document.querySelector('.topbar').innerHTML = '<a onclick="myfunction(\'show\');">Какая-то надпись</a>';`

Далее добавляю саму функцию `function myfunction(text){ alert(text); }`
Однако, это не срабатывает. Ошибка: `Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined`.

Знаю, что можно вынести скрипт в отдельный файл, а далее просто подключать его.

```
var New_js = document.createElement('script');
    New_js.type = 'text/javascript';
    New_js.src = 'log.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(New_js);
```

Или добавлять через:

`document.querySelector('.topbar').addEventListener("click", function(){myfunction("show")}, false);`

Хотелось бы все держать в одном файле.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие еще имеются варианты?

И почему не срабатывает стандартный — `function myfunction(text){ alert(text); }`?

Comment: [[ENG] Тут нашел хороший ответ.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378199/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-with-onclick )

Но хотелось бы узнать о других вариантах (если имеются)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined

Функции на момент вызова ещё нет в куче. Почему - это хороший вопрос, на который без кода не ответишь.
Вешать обработчик надобно через `addEventListener`, забудьте архаизмы типа `onclick`.
И это будет работать в одном файле.